# CSS positional text correctly over flash movie with resize

Tags: html, css, browser

A very annoying problem with Flash that when the browser window is resized the flash stays in the middle.

If you see [this site](http://flowerstudioshop.co.uk/) with the blog link over the left menu, how can force this to always stay in the same position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash insists on being in front, so you cannot use CSS to position HTML elements over the top of a flash movie unfortunately.

Comment: Not even using the wmode transparent? It is in fact working its just the way that the flash movie is positioned

Comment: transparent just means it's transparent. The flash movie is still sitting on top.  Can you rephrase your question to make the positioning issue a little clearer?